# Expansion of Universe

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, solar-system, space-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why space expansion affects matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/why-space-expansion-affects-matter)

If the Expansion is prevalent, i.e. it is observable and true then shouldn't that result in the expansion of the Milky Way galaxy, eventually our solar system would expand resulting in increase in the planetary distances (from the sun). Could the escape of Pluto be an example to this phenomena ? And is the Expansion resulting in increase in the sizes of the galactic objects ?

Comment: As cited in Arthur Beiser's Modern Physics ,to explain the expansion of the universe and validation of the Hubble's law an example of the inflating balloon and the perspective of an ant sitting  on it has been discussed. I wanted to know that, as the balloon is inflated the speckles on it gradually get farther away from each other, but also they increase in size as well. If the same thing be applied to the Universe wouldn't the above asked statement be right ?

Comment: This has been addressed several times. See the duplicate and the several questions in its "Linked" sidebar.